# is it possible to replace different array value(s) with different keys from different array

Tags: php, arrays, replace

```
[1] => ooooooo
[2] => ooooooo
[3] => ooooooo
[4] => ooooooo
[5] => ------------empty
[6] => ooooooo
[7] => ooooooo
[8] => ooooooo
[9] => ooooooo
[10] => ------------empty
[11] => ooooooo
[12] => ooooooo
[13] => ------------empty
[14] => ooooooo
[15] => ooooooo
```

replace array1  above: "------------empty"   with the below array2, keeping the keys of array1

```
[1] => xxxxx
[2] => yyyyy
[3] => zzzzz
```

SO asks me to add explanation---a picture paint more than a thousand words(I believe?) what the heck should I say more. I had a wonderful time last christmas, I hope you did too :)
the result would look like this:

Maybe I should say that it's a necessity to find and replace automaticlly--so NO manual or individual inputs.  EACH "---empty" could possibly be at a different position on every call

```
[1] => ooooooo
[2] => ooooooo
[3] => ooooooo
[4] => ooooooo
[5] => xxxxx
[6] => ooooooo
[7] => ooooooo
[8] => ooooooo
[9] => ooooooo
[10] => yyyyy
[11] => ooooooo
[12] => ooooooo
[13] => zzzzz
[14] => ooooooo
[15] => ooooooo
```

Comment: Please, be precise, it's not clear what really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes, you can just say:

```
array1[INDEX] = array2[ANOTHER_INDEX];
```

But you have to be careful the two arrays contain the same type as well as that indexes are within the size of the arrays

I guess what you wanted to do is:

```
array1[5] = array2[1]; // replace '------------empty` with 'xxxxx'
array1[10] = array2[2]; // replace '------------empty` with 'yyyyy' 
array1[13] = array[3]; // replace '------------empty` with 'zzzzz'
```

Note that in most programming languages, array indexes start at 0 so all your indexes should probably be less by 1.

Here is some pseudo-code to do it in a loop:

```
int i = 0; // index for array1
int j = 0; // index for array2
while( i < array1.size ) 
{
    if(array1[i] equals "------------empty" AND j < array2.size) 
    {
        array1[i] = array2[j];
        increment j;
    }
    increment i;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, here is the PHP code to do it in a loop.

```php
$size1 = count($array1);
$size2 = count($array2);
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
while($i < $size1) {
    if($array1[$i] == "------------empty" && $j < $size2) {
        $array1[$i] = $array2[$j];
        $j = $j + 1;
    }
    $i = $i + 1;
}
```

If you are comparing objects you should [take a look at this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php)

[**`Here is a full running example`**](http://ideone.com/S4Cdut)

Comment: Thankyou @nem for your time, as in the last part of my edited question, I can actually do this manually, but my arrays are fetched in two batches, resulting in in two different arrays and keys...I've treid so much that it's easier NOT to explain what I have tried...merge, combine, replace, and individual combinationsbut I can't seem to get the individual keys as variables from array1 with  "-----empty" in order to to tell array2 to swap the values

Comment: is this just plain stupid thinking from my part and simply not possible in PHP? your answer is good if one knows the keys, but in my case they may vary each call

Comment: THANKS @nem...That did the job perfectly...how can I thank without a rep :(

Comment: I'm terribly sorry nem, but how do I accept...this is new to me and it's 05:30 am(sleepless)